# Spring data Instant conversion to Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I've been going through `spring-data` source to check how exactly instances of `Instant` class are mapped to DB. I was wondering why this conversion here is applied:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/b69ef25dc28007b40fd951fab936a1ff31e8fc4f/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters.java#L194

This test explains my concerns https://gist.github.com/jkornata/f89a15406c0c1bf2590dbf7982149d7c

What am I missing?

Comment: Those converters aren't used to convert to a DB representation. BUt rather from incoming web request parameters to a date. Conversion to DB is done using the default types specified in JPA or in additional converter libraries like the hibernate-java8 lib (now deprecated and part of the default hibernate-entitymanager).

Comment: @M.Deinum Those _are_ plain converters for the Converter Service infrastructure and might be used by several Spring components. In particular, some NoSQL databases have `Date` support but haven't yet updated to 2014.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- true, however I assumed that, due to mentioning DB, that it was JPA related, and in that case the converters don't apply.

Comment: @M.Deinum alrighty, maybe it's not used for the database conversions but logic stays the same, doesn't it (included test)? Those converters are used here also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/threeten/Jsr310JpaConverters.java

Comment: Which are only included if you add that package to be scanned, if not they aren't used and the defaults of the JPA provider (probably hibernate) apply. Hibernate has its own support so no need for additional converters.

Comment: That's a fair point, although question kinda stays the same. Does it make any sense `Date.from(source.atZone(systemDefault()).toInstant())` when source is an `Instant` already